# how to terminate Jupyter Notebook/ JupyterLab service in a slurm cluster?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cluster-computing

After requesting a task to a cluster, the system will allocate some resources as required(CPU, RAM, GPU, max running time, etc) to a task, then start a jupyter service instance and send url to user. For example, if I ask cluster for maxed 6 hours of a GPU, and my training task finished within 4 hours, I don't want the gpu to be idle in the next 2 hours, I hope to terminate my job and free the resources. My question is, how to stop jupyter service(not the IPython instance but its parent process) on the web page since I don't know how the cluster start the service, but I guess it will remain the task as long as the jupyter instance is alive.